# Hide a JButton (image) after click

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing

I've create a program with a JButton(image) and a normal image, now if you click the normal button a image will show, now i have program that the JButton(image) will hide if you click the normal button but i dont work and i get a fault code

```
package View;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


import Controller.HideController;
import Controller.HomeController;
import Controller.SelectieController;

public class Selectie extends JFrame{

private static String Vermeer = "Vermeer";

private JLabel label, label1, label2;
    private JButton keeper, kruis;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Container window = getContentPane();

 public Selectie()
    {
        initGUI();

    }

    public void initGUI()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Jari");
        setSize(800,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        label = new JLabel();       
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 266, 800);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        window.add(label);

        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setBounds(266, 0, 266, 800);
        label1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label1.setOpaque(true);
        window.add(label1);

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setBounds(532, 0, 266, 800);
        label2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label2.setOpaque(true);
        window.add(label2);

        JLabel foto = new JLabel();
        label1.add(foto);

        kruis = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Ajax/src/img/logotje.gif"));
        kruis.setBorderPainted(false);
        kruis.setBounds(40, 150, 188, 188);
        label1.add(kruis);

        keeper = new JButton("1. "+""+" Kenneth Vermeer");
        Cursor cur = keeper.getCursor();
        keeper.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        keeper.setBounds(20, 50, 186, 12);
        keeper.setFocusable(false);
        keeper.setBorderPainted(false);
        keeper.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        keeper.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        keeper.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        keeper.setActionCommand(Vermeer);
        label.add(keeper);

SelectieController s1 = new SelectieController(keeper);

        keeper.addActionListener(s1);

}

    HideController h1 = new HideController(keeper, kruis);
        {
        keeper.addActionListener(h1);
        }

}
```

The action listener class:

```
package Controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HideController implements ActionListener {

    private JButton keeper, logo;
    private static String Vermeer = "Vermeer";

    public HideController(JButton vermeer, JButton kruis)
    {
        keeper = vermeer;
        logo = kruis;
  //Kenneth Vermeer
     try
    {
        keeper.setVisible(true);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     logo.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        // Kenneth Vermeer
        if (Vermeer.equals(actionCommand)) 
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {                       
                    logo.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
    }



    }}
```

I hope someone could help me, thanks

Comment: 1) I get a fault code ... please post it as well. 2) Instead of posting a bunch of non-relevant code (like all the labels, the null layout ... ) post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) 3) Do not use a null layout 4) Please respect Java naming conventions

Comment: Why you adding your `JButton` to your `JLabel` ? Or is it something you just did by mistake ? `label1.add(kruis);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button gone you can use `window.remove(keeper)`. If you want no image but still want the button to be there, you can try `logo = null`, which will set the icon on logo to nothing, leaving you with a white box. If you are coding on Windows, you can add a background color with `keeper.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue)` or whatever color your background is, however the Mac OS's look and feel will not allow this for some reason. (you can change the look and feel with, but that is fairly complicated) If you have a more complex background i would suggest taking a sample from the right point with a screenshot (with the button commented out in the code) and setting logo to that image.